# Last Year vs Current Selected Year

Tags: powerbi, dax, analysis

I have been creating a dashboard in which I am trying to showing current Selected year vs last year analysis. Please see the below image :

[image]

As you see in the above image, 2020 year selected from the slicer and 2020 sales is 4.30M.
Expectation :  I want to show the last year difference with Arrow sign means if the current year sales is greater than last year than "Green upper arrow" and if the last year sales greater than current year then "Red down arrow".

Thing I Tried :  I have created a DAX, but it not showing any value to me :
Previous Year Sales = CALCULATE(sum(Orders[Sales]),PREVIOUSYEAR(Orders[Order Date]))

Option 2 : I have also tried this one (it show me value but desired results):

same period last year = CALCULATE(Sum(Orders[Sales]),SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(Orders[Order Date]))

Expected Output ( Current Year vs last year percentage with Arrow sign) :

[image]

Sample data link :
[http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~hwshen/Melbourne/Data/Superstore.xlsx](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/%7Ehwshen/Melbourne/Data/Superstore.xlsx)
How can I achieve the above ?

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you shared a sample model with sample values and expected outcome.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply @mxix
Please see the expected output. I have updated the question. 
I am unable to share sample work book in comments.

Comment: No need for the workbooks just some sample tables with data in Text format on the question Body.

Comment: I have added the sample data set link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The percentage should be straight foward. Keep in mind you need a DATE TABLE or use the automatic datetime created by power bi, for that you need to reference it with ".[Date]"

```
same period last year = CALCULATE(Sum(Orders[Sales]),SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(Orders[Order Date].[Date]))

Sales YoY % = 
    VAR _ly = [same period last year]
RETURN
    DIVIDE(_ly-Sum(Orders[Sales]),_ly)
```

Format you [Sales YoY %] measure as a percentage.

The visual part you can do it multiple ways, cards, HTML, KPIs Visuals or Table/Matrix conditional formating.

Comment: I have added a date table : 
Table = CALENDARAUTO(6)
then join the Date with order date(.
Now the "Same Period Last Year" has data in it. but this measure has data for last three years not for just last year.

Comment: replace the Orders[Order Date].[Date] with the column of your date table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I have updated the measure by replace the "order[date]" to  Date[Date]:
same period last year = CALCULATE(Sum(Orders[Sales]),SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Date'[Date]))
After this, slicer and related numbers working fine.

Comment: But I have some questions : 
1. I have created a date table by doing " CALENDARAUTO(6) ". Now un-necessary years appearing in the slicer which are not needed. like 2021,2011 etc.
How can I set table dates according to my original table Dates? and what will happen if I am getting data from SQL-Server and it is updating on daily basis? Table dates will be set accordingly?
2. When I am not select any year from slicer than number are aggregated on all previous years instead of just last year 2019.

Comment: You can check if just one year is selected with HASONEVALUE(). And you can use CALENDAR instead of CALENDARAUTO and generate it based on dates.